# Linux - How do I find out how many bytes have been written during a file copy?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, sd-card, copy

In linux (Ubuntu), I use a file manager to copy a large file e.g (500mb) to a USB sd card.

According to the gui, it shows completion in about 5 or 6 seconds (the destination file size is the same as the source).
But I know it's not done because the card reader is still blinking and the file manager dialog won't close.
It's obvious the copy is being buffered.
Even the terminal command stat -c%s filename shows the full filesize (it's lying).
After 50 secs, the dialog closes and I know that it's done.

My question is how do I find out how many 'actual' bytes have been written to the sd card at any moment ?
Is there a command that can do this ?

Comment: Please note; `mb` can only be read as "milli-bit" (compare to "MB").

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to try:

An asynchronous bash script that does:

```
prev=$(df --output=avail /home/$USER/Downloads/ | tail -n 1)
```

... just before the process starts, then;

```
coproc CPY cp source dest
```

to launch the copy with `$CPY_PID` set, holding the "PID", and...

```
echo $(( $(df --output=avail /home/$USER/Downloads/ | tail -n 1) - $prev )) && \ 
sleep 1
```

... in a loop defined by `while ! ps --pid $CPY_PID ; do ... ; done` during the process.

Will display the amount of bytes copied so far...
... when `/home/$USER/Downloads/` is om the same partition / disk.

Adjust for a known (total) size of the file(s) subject to the copy / move, and maybe display the progress as a percentage instead.

And in the end, launching the copy, and doing all the above, might well be possible to do in e.g. Python.

***Ref:** mostly `man bash`, but also `man ps`*

---

Hints for Python scripting:

```
$ python
...
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.disk_usage('/home')
usage(total=245002539008, used=188822900736, free=43662839808)
>>> t,u,f=shutil.disk_usage('/home')
>>> f
43662839808
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> f=Path('/home/hannu/.bashrc')
>>> f
PosixPath('/home/hannu/.bashrc')
>>> f.stat().st_size
3771
>>> quit()
$ ls -l .bashrc 
-rw-r--r-- 1 hannu hannu 3771 mar 11  2021 .bashrc
$
```

Copy a file?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/123212 and
https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html
... but: that needs to be run in parallel with the above,
so may be that:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/89228 gives better possibilities.

---

Then, in the end, the maybe simplest:

`$ dd if=/from/file bs=100K of=/to/file progress=status`

... but: does this have the same problem as seen in the GUI?

***ref:** https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-dd-command-show-progress-while-coping/*

Comment: Indeed dd was the answer! Tks.